# Make a lozenge diagram

Tags: xymatrix

I would like to create a lozenge diagram with the package `\xymatrix`.
Here is the code I wrote :

```
\[\xymatrix{
  & M\ar@{-}[ld]^{n}_{G} \ar@{-}[rd]^{m^2}& \\
  H\ar@{-}[rd]^{m^2} && Z(M)\ar@{-}[ld]^{n}_{G} \\
  & K& \\
  }\]
```

And here is the result.

[image: result]

I would like to know how to make it more beautiful : it looks like that the right part of the lozenge is longer than the left part.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: One possibility is to use `Z\rlap{(M)}`. Not elegant solution, but satisfactory one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `tikz-cd` and to make the two objects in the middle row the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=dash]
& M \arrow[ld,"G"',"n"] \arrow[rd,"m^2"] \\
\mathmakebox[0.5em][r]{H} \arrow[rd,"m^2"] &&
\mathmakebox[0.5em][l]{Z(M)} \arrow[ld,"G"',"n"] \\
& K
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar trick almost works with Xy-pic.

```
\[
\xymatrix{
  & M\ar@{-}[ld]^{n}_{G} \ar@{-}[rd]^{m^2}& \\
  \mathmakebox[0.5em][r]{H} \ar@{-}[rd]^{m^2} &&
  \mathmakebox[0.5em][l]{Z(M)} \ar@{-}[ld]^{n}_{G} \\
  & K& \\
}
\]
```

[image]